# how to create a toolbar with maxscript in 3dsmax

Tags: 3dsmax, maxscript

I want to create a custom toolbar by maxscript, but after searching the help doc, I found nothing, anyone who can give me any suggestion? Thanks a million!

I know how to create a toolbar button, like define a macroscript and drag it to the toolbar. But now, I need to create a toolbar that could include serval buttons, is there any way can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

try this method:

```
ROLLOUT Toolbar_TMP_RLLT "TMP_RLLT" width:105 height:85
(
    button btn1 "btn1" height:14 pos:[35,1] tooltip:"btn1"
    on btn1 pressed do print "btn1"
)
CREATEDIALOG Toolbar_TMP_RLLT POS:[0,100] width:105
CUI.REGISTERDIALOGBAR Toolbar_TMP_RLLT
CUI.DOCKDIALOGBAR Toolbar_TMP_RLLT #cui_dock_right
```

Comment: i get a _Runtime error: Requires a Rollout or RolloutFloater, got: undefined_ running this in the listener. please add a button example.